# Issue with changing an image altered by a select HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a website for exercise/active wear. In the shop subpage, I have separate product cards. Those products that have differing colors will have a dropdown menu in which the user can select the color and view it on the webpage. I have this working for me in JavaScript.

The error that I've encountered is trying to get the images to change (between a front view of the attire & back view) upon hovering over and out of the image element. I will attach the code below:

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="item_4">
            <img src="img/apparel/shop_item_4.png" style="width:100%" alt="Hoody" id="item_4_switch">
            <h1>Apparel Item #1</h1>
            <p>$19.99</p>
            <select id="shop_item_4_switch">
                <option value="img/apparel/shop_item_4.png">Black</option>
                <option value="img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_1.png">Blue</option>
                <option value="img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_3.png">Red</option>
            </select>
            <p><button>Purchase</button></p>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("shop_item_4_switch").onchange = changeShopItemFour;

function changeShopItemFour() {
  var img = document.getElementById("item_4_switch");
  img.src = this.value;
}

document.getElementById('item_4_switch').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  
  if (this.src === "img/apparel/shop_item_4.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt.png";
  } else if (this.src === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_1.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_2.png";
  } else if (this.src === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_3.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_4.png"
  }
  
});

document.getElementById('item_4_switch').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  
  if (this.src === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt.png") {
    this.src = 'img/apparel/shop_item_4.png';
  } else if (this.src === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_2.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_1.png";
  } else if (this.src === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_4.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_3.png"
  }

});
```

---

I am trying to get the *if statements* to alternate between a frontal view of the clothing item and the back view based on mousing over and off of the image element.

I feel like I am making an amateur mistake somewhere, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard. I have resolved this issue.

I have made it to where I can hover in and out and alternate between a front-view and back-view of the different color options of the clothing item.

```
document.getElementById('item_4_switch').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  
  var x = document.getElementById('shop_item_4_switch')

  if (x.value === "img/apparel/shop_item_4.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt.png";
  } else if (x.value === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_1.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_2.png";
  } else if (x.value === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_3.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_4.png"
  }
  
});

document.getElementById('item_4_switch').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  
  var x = document.getElementById('shop_item_4_switch')

  if (x.value === "img/apparel/shop_item_4.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4.png";
  } else if (x.value === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_1.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_1.png";
  } else if (x.value === "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_3.png") {
    this.src = "img/apparel/shop_item_4_alt_3.png"
  }
  
});
```